# Is it possible to run a macro on button in Task Pane(web) using Office App?

Tags: office-js, office365api, office-addins, office365-apps, office-app

I have created a macro in VBA. I want to call that macro on click on button in Task Add-in button.

Is there any way to run macro using button provided in Task Add-in panel?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Office-JS & VBA Addin How to mix together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45156707/office-js-vba-addin-how-to-mix-together)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75299140/can-i-call-a-pre-xisting-macro-via-the-office-add-in-javascript-library

Comment: Short answer, yes, through customxmlparts events. Essentially on click you can send a formatted xmlpart that excel will listen for. Even better, since word is your host, you can actually listen to node modification events from the addin side.

Answer (score 1):

Office.hs API doesn't provide this functionality. If this is a new feature you want to include in the future, I suggest you submit a feedback at https://officespdev.uservoice.com/

You may read the thread from [MSDN: Run Word Macro - Office App Javascript API](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/SqlServer/en-US/cc4bfdf6-9d72-41fe-80f3-2ea9c85e9b21/run-word-macro-office-app-javascript-api?forum=appsforoffice)