# Is is possible to call Excel JS API from Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, office-js, excel-addins

I have created Web AddIns for Excel . I am also using VBA script in this excel.

Is it possible to call/refer Excel JS API method of Web AddIns from VBA script.Please share code if possible.

I want to call excel JS API function on focus of Cell using VBA and Excel JS API

Comment: No, it's not possible. Closest you could get, *maybe*, would be to put controls in the Ribbon. Then, *possibly*, the code could be called using `SendKeys` to emulate the keyboard presses used to run the control.

Comment: How we can call a excel js function on focus(Edit) mode of cell. I know change/selection-change is one option , but we have to change text for cell. I want to call function on keypress or onfocus of cell

Comment: maybe this answer can help someone https://stackoverflow.com/a/49197187/7990095