# Call Office 365 new-style add-in from VBA

Tags: excel, vba, office365, office-js

I'm maintaining a legacy Excel workbook that has a significant amount done in VBA. For threading's sake, I need to move some of that work out of VBA. I have prototyped a DLL written in C#, but deployment (with registration) is more difficult.

Can you interact with the new HTML5 style add-ins using VBA? So, in this case, writing a function in Javascript, and then calling it with specific parameters from the existing VBA macro. If so, how?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45156707/office-js-vba-addin-how-to-mix-together

Comment: Or maybe https://ramblings.mcpher.com/get-started-snippets/step-by-step-guides/how-to-add-flightpaths-on-a-map/how-to-use-javascript-from-vba/ might be useful

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not a scenarios supported by Microsoft nowadays.