# Can I call a pre-xisting macro via the Office Add-In javascript library?

Tags: excel, odata, office-js, office-addins, excel-web-addins

I am developing an Excel Add-In to list, select, and retrieve an OData source. I'd like to be able to call a macro that opens excels Data / Get Data / From Other Sources / From OData Feed and fills in the URL field according to the user's previous selection.

I've searched microsft documentation and google but find no mention of executing a macro from the Office javascript library.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Office-JS & VBA Addin How to mix together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45156707/office-js-vba-addin-how-to-mix-together)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Office JavaScript API doesn't provide anything for that.

You can post or vote for an existing feature request on [Tech Community](https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions) where they are considered when the Office dev team goes through the planning process.